# AngularJS - Unit Testing a view template with ng-if on the root element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm using requirejs, karma, jasmine, ng-html2js and ngMock

While unit testing my views, i do this:

```
view = compile(angular.element(html))(scope);
scope.$digest();
```

The view contains something like this:

```
<div ng-if="expression()">More stuff</div>
```

Now if i log the view`console.log(view);`

I see this `Object{0: <!-- ngIf: expression() -->, length: 1}`

The `expression()` returns true. But the view is empty??

When i change it to an `ng-show` i get to see the entire `<div>` in the log

This:

```
<div ng-show="expression()">More stuff</div>
```

`console.log(view)` shows:

```
 Object{0: <div class="ng-scope" ng-show="expression()">More stuff</div>, length: 1}
```

And an ng-hide of expression() also gives this output:

```
Object{0: <div class="ng-scope ng-hide" ng-hide="expression()">More stuff</div>, length: 1}
```

Why does this happen? I have an `ng-if` inside this `div` which is evaluated correctly. Also, i tried putting an `ng-init` on that `div`. The method linked got executed, just the view doesn't come out of `$compile`.

Is this behavior expected? What am i missing?

Here's another example:

```
var ascope = scope.$new(true);
ascope.name = "Test";
var view = compile("<p ng-if='true'>{{ name }}</p>")(ascope);
ascope.$digest();
console.log(view);
```

Change the ng-if to ng-show and see the difference..

This works if i wrap a `<div>` around the ng-if element

Comment: either way your view has stuff in it. What you want is to name your div by id and get that.  And when you say expression returns true, can we see how you test for this?

Comment: The expression() is able to drive behavior with ng-show.